# Updating Label of a View Controller by a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, viewcontroller

I am new in Xcode5 and IOS7 and I am having problems updating the text of a couple of labels and an image. I have a `NavigationController` -> `InitialViewController` (`UITableView` with custom Rows) and when you click in a Row I want to show a `UIViewController` with the information of the previous `RowCell`, the information is stored in a `NSMutableArray` filled with `NSDictionary` with keys(name, team, image). The problem is that the View is not updating the text of the labels and the image, I can't find what is wrong in the code below. I have debugged that it is working until the `pushView`, once there the information inside the label and the image is not getting updated.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSDictionary *playersVC = [players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    ProfilePlayerViewController *profile = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfilePlayerViewController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];
    [profile.playerName setText:[playersVC objectForKey:@"name"]];
    [profile.teamName setText:[playersVC objectForKey:@"team"]];
    [profile.playerImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[playersVC objectForKey:@"image"]]];
}
```

The rest of configuration it seems to be right, I am just following part of a tutorial with IOS5 and it seems to work for them.

Comment: Have you tried setting the properties on profile before pushing the view controller?

Comment: I would bet that playersVC is nil.

Comment: Yes, I have set playerName, teamName and playerImage. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work this way. You have to create a @property NSDictionary in your ProfilePlayerViewController. Then when you click on a row at your first View Controller, assign that NSDictionary to that property like this.

```
NSDictionary *playersVC = [players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
ProfilePlayerViewController *profile = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfilePlayerViewController"];
profile.myDictionary = playersVC ;
```

Now at ViewDidLoad method of your ProfilePlayerViewController , update the labels and images. It will certainly work. Hope it helps.

Comment: this mostly right, but unreliable as the myDictionary value may not be updated as of the viewDidLoad method call.  Best to put things like this in viewWillAppear.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and it works perfectly Ayon!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds great ! Then I can expect an upvote and accepted answer :)

Comment: @Ayon he cant upvote yet but you get my vote, hopefully he accepts it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create instance variables in your `ProfilePlayerViewController` like

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *playerName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *team;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *imageName;
```

After you instantiate this `ViewController`, set these properties from the dictionary, like so:

```
ProfilePlayerViewController *profile = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfilePlayerViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];
profile.playerName =  [playersVC objectForKey:@"name"];
profile.team = [playersVC objectForKey:@"team"];
profile.imageName = [playersVC objectForKey:@"image"];
```

And in your `[self viewDidLoad]` method, set your UI Elements.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      self.playerNameLabel.text = self.playerName;
      self.teamLabel.text = self.team;
      [self.playerImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.imagName]];
}
```

This should solve your issue.